# Sql Merging multiple records into one record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with two columns user_id and tags.

```
  user_id    tags
    1    <tag1><tag4>
    1    <tag1><tag2>
    1    <tag3><tag2>
    2    <tag1><tag2>
    2    <tag4><tag5>
    3    <tag4><tag1>
    3    <tag4><tag1>
    4    <tag1><tag2>
```

I want to merge this two records into one record like this.

```
  user_id    tags
    1    tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4
    2    tags, tag2, tag4, tag5
    3    tag4, tag1
    4    tag1, tag2
```

How can i get this? Can anyone help me out.
Also need to convert tags field into array [].
I don't have much knowledge on typical sql commads. I just know the basics. I am a ruby on rails guy.

Comment: For this to achieve you have to write **SP** or **Function** with **Query**.

Comment: can you knowledge me with the more info on this. I need to sql only for this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the GROUP_CONCAT function in mysql.**[A good example is here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)**

In your case it would be something like:

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(tags) FROM tablename GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Its not something you can do readily in SQL, as you are talking about pulling apart data within a field.  If you had originally limited the tags field to just 1 tag, you would be able to do it.

Comment: @ashwinkumar to get unique/sorted tags, you have to use a sub-select and then do the GROUP_CONCAT against just the unique row.s

Answer (score 1):

duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16218616/sql-marching-values-in-column-a-with-more-than-1-value-in-column-b/16218678#16218678

```
select user_id, group_concat(tags separator ',')
from t
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -:

> SELECT t2.userid,
>      stuff((
>       SELECT ', ' + t1.tags
>       FROM table_name as t1
>       where t1.userid = t2.userid
>       FOR XML PATH('') 
>       ), 1, 2, '')
>   FROM table_name as t2 
>   GROUP BY t2.userid

I hope this helps you out.

Check the example -:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/85c89/6